# How do I download a CSV from a link using Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, download, axios

I need help downloading a [CSV](https://www.jobnimbus.com/) file which requires the user to be logged in. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY64j.jpg) is the screen I'm on. The CSV file I'm interested in can be found at [this link](https://app.jobnimbus.com/api2/ReportDownload?type=csv&id=fbe2459fdf6e4c089b35e2631472137e&rid=null).

Any idea how I can download the CSV file from that link using Node?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the approach of the API that servers the CSV, there are several ways that you can authenticate your request.

The most common are:

- `BASIC`, when you log with a username/password;
- `BEARER TOKEN`, when you are already logged and has a token that represents your session;
- `API_KEY/CLIENT_KEY/AUTH_KEY...`, when the service provides a key that will identify the request;

It seems that the website's API (JobNimbus) provides an `API_KEY` type of auth, you can see it [here](https://support.jobnimbus.com/api-keys).

Follow the steps provided on the link to get your API key, and use the provided key to make the request using the `fetch` API or some library like `axios`.